# Make update query with append(concat) using sequelize in nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am using Sequelize ORM, i had a need a help with update query.
I have a model, **user**(id, name, mobile).

While update, I want a particular field to get append instead of getting replaced.
Eg. Mobile number should be added to existing value instead of replacing

> User.update({mobile: 87477777888}, {id: userId})
>   .success(function(user){
>   console.log(user);
>   }).error(function(user){
>       console.log("Error in update");
>   });

Comment: what about update manually the instance ? or getting the value, then concatenate the two and then update with the new value ?

Comment: Currently I am doing get and concatenate and update. But I am looking for some way to do without doing get.

Comment: I don't think it's possible but you can create a class method to abstract it